# How to return numbers after semicolons in string only corresponding to certain dates?

Tags: python, string, list

```
['2017-07-17', '2017-07-27', '2017-07-17;14', '2017-07-17;5', '2017-07-19;11', '2017-07-19;13', '2017-07-23;4', '2017-07-27;-1']
```

I want to extract all the numbers to the right of the semicolon corresponding to a date. For example, with date `'2017-07-17'`, I want to return the list `[14,5]`. And for date `2017-07-23` I just want to return `[4]`.

How can I do this? I only know of iterating through the indices to extract numbers but that's not going to get me lists of numbers corresponding to certain dates.

`for eventIndex in range(2,len(path)):
   curr_date = path[eventIndex].split(';')[0]`

Will only get me the corresponding numbers traversed, but I just have no idea how to get lists corresponding to each date.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far; Stack Overflow is a question answering service, not a code writing service. Consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You know how to iterate the list. Good. Now you need to process the strings. I suggest reading the Python documentation on [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to see which weapons you have available.

Comment: So far I've tried `for eventIndex in range(2,len(path)):
curr_date = path[eventIndex].split(';')[0]`

Comment: But that only gets me the corresponding number after each date traversed.

Answer (score 5):

Choose a proper data structure e.g. a `collections.defaultdict` with `list` as the factory:

```
In [1233]: out = collections.defaultdict(list)

In [1234]: lst = ['2017-07-17', '2017-07-27', '2017-07-17;14', '2017-07-17;5', '2017-07-19;11', '2017-07-19;13', '2017-07-23;4', '2017-07-27;-1']

In [1235]: for i in lst:
      ...:     m, _, n = i.partition(';')
      ...:     if n:
      ...:         out[m].append(n)
      ...:         

In [1236]: out
Out[1236]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'2017-07-17': ['14', '5'],
             '2017-07-19': ['11', '13'],
             '2017-07-23': ['4'],
             '2017-07-27': ['-1']})

In [1237]: out['2017-07-17']
Out[1237]: ['14', '5']

In [1238]: out['2017-07-23']
Out[1238]: ['4']
```

Here, we're iterating over the list, partitioning strings on `;`, and using the date portion as the key to the `out` dictionary with values being the right sided substrings appended.

Answer (score 1):

Join your list with a character that is not present in your list (*e.g.* `|`), then use a regex to find the numbers that are after a semicolon after the date in question:

```
import re

l = ['2017-07-17', '2017-07-27', '2017-07-17;14', '2017-07-17;5', '2017-07-19;11', '2017-07-19;13', '2017-07-23;4', '2017-07-27;-1']

>>> re.findall('2017-07-17;(\d+)','|'.join(l))
['14', '5']

>>> re.findall('2017-07-23;(\d+)','|'.join(l))
['4']
```

If you need them as numeric dtypes and not strings, use `map(int,...)`:

```
>>> list(map(int,re.findall('2017-07-17;(\d+)','|'.join(l))))
[14, 5]
```